# Hibernate 5.4.3 Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, xml, maven

Ive looked into similar solutions and none worked for me. Hoping I could find some answers here...

Using Eclipse JEE (JDK 12) 
These is the errorlist i get when i try to run my "main" method

> Aug 05, 2019 3:12:36 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
>   INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.3.Final}
>   Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
>       at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:133)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:165)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
>       at main.Main.main(Main.java:18)
>   Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[8,109]
>   Message: The reference to entity "useSSL" must end with the ';' delimiter.]
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:485)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:463)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:435)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:126)
>       ... 5 more
>   Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[8,109]
>   Message: The reference to entity "useSSL" must end with the ';' delimiter.
>       at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:652)
>       at java.xml/com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:277)
>       at java.xml/javax.xml.stream.util.EventReaderDelegate.peek(EventReaderDelegate.java:98)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor$NamespaceAddingEventReader.peek(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:254)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.handleCharacters(StAXEventConnector.java:179)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.bridge(StAXEventConnector.java:141)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:460)
>       ... 7 more

Here is my hibernate configuration (located in the /src folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
        root
        Se2018Se
        true
        true
        create-drop
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

```
    <mapping resource="item.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

and this is the code i wrote to the main class

```
package main;
```

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Starting test");

    Item item = new Item();
    item.setName("Bamba");


    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session hession = sessionFactory.openSession(); // hession = hibernate session
    Transaction tx = hession.beginTransaction();

    hession.save(item);
    tx.commit();

}
```

}